# Преобразование функции в нужный вид

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность

Пытаюсь создать поток на С++ в linux через `pthread`. Написал класс `Threads` для создание потоков. Написал класс простейшего сервера. Оба класса работают по отдельности. Потом делаю так:

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include "Threads.h"

class Server {
public:
    Server(int portnum);
    virtual ~Server();
    void* ThreadFunc(void* arg);

private:
    void InitVars();

    int hSocket, newsockfd, iPort;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[255];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    bool ServerRunning;
    Threads* thread;

};

#endif  /* SERVER_H */

#include "Server.h"

Server::Server(int portnum) {
    InitVars();
    // Create socket
    hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(hSocket < 0)
        throw "ERROR opening socket";
    iPort = portnum;
    // Clear and setup sockaddr_in
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(iPort);

    if(bind(hSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        throw "ERROR binding";

    listen(hSocket, 10);
    int i = 1;

    thread = new Threads(&Server::ThreadFunc, &i);
//    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
//    newsockfd = accept(hSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &clilen);
//    if(newsockfd < 0)
//        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR on accept");
//    
//    n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
//    if(n < 0)
//        throw "ERROR reading from socket";
//    
//    printf("%s\n", buffer);
//    
//    n = write(newsockfd, "I got your message", 18);
//    if(n < 0)
//        throw "ERROR writing to socket";
}

Server::~Server() {
    if(hSocket > 0)
        close(hSocket);
    if(newsockfd > 0)
        close(newsockfd);
}

void Server::InitVars() {
    ServerRunning = true;
    memset((char*) &serv_addr, 0x00, sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset((char*) &cli_addr, 0x00, sizeof(cli_addr));
    memset(buffer, 0x00, 255);
}

void* Server::ThreadFunc(void* arg) {
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(hSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if(newsockfd < 0)
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR on accept");
    n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
    if(n < 0)
        throw "ERROR reading from socket";

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    n = write(newsockfd, "I got your message", 18);
    if(n < 0)
        throw "ERROR writing to socket";
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> `Server.cpp:29:49: ошибка: нет подходящей функции для вызова «Threads::Threads(void* (Server::*)(void*), int*)» так как конструктор описан как Threads(void*(*thread_func)(void *), void *__restrict arg);`

Как исправить?

Вот код моих потоков. Я только учусь работать с потоками так что не ругайтесь =).

```
#ifndef THREADS_H
#define THREADS_H
#include <pthread.h>

class Threads {
public:
    Threads(void*(*thread_func)(void *), void *__restrict arg);
    virtual ~Threads();

private:
    pthread_t _thread;

};

#endif  /* THREADS_H */

#include "Threads.h"

Threads::Threads(void*(*thread_func)(void *), void *__restrict arg) {
    pthread_create(&_thread, NULL, thread_func, arg);
}

Threads::~Threads() {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно исправить так:

```
class Server {
public:
    Server(int portnum);
    virtual ~Server();

private:
    struct ThreadParams {
        Server* s;
        int i;
    };
    ThreadParams threadParams;

    static void* ThreadFunc(void* arg);
    void InitVars();

    int hSocket, newsockfd, iPort;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[255];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    bool ServerRunning;
    Threads* thread;
};
```

и далее:

```
...
threadParams.s = this;
threadParams.i = 1;

thread = new Threads(&Server::ThreadFunc, static_cast<void*>(&threadParams));
...
...
void* Server::ThreadFunc(void* arg) {
    ThreadParams* tp = static_cast<ThreadParams*>(arg);
    Server& s = *(tp->s);

    s.clilen = sizeof(s.cli_addr);
    s.newsockfd = accept(s.hSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &s.cli_addr, &s.clilen);
    if(s.newsockfd < 0)
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR on accept");
    s.n = read(s.newsockfd, s.buffer, 255);
    if(s.n < 0)
        throw "ERROR reading from socket";

    printf("%s\n", s.buffer);

    s.n = write(s.newsockfd, "I got your message", 18);
    if(s.n < 0)
        throw "ERROR writing to socket";
}
```

Но вообще, если уж писать на C++, то нужно использовать стандартный класс thread, или, если компилятор не поддерживает C++11, взять thread из boost.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас в конструкторе второй аргумент типа `void*`, а Вы передаете `int*`. Естественно, компилятор будет ругаться. Надо привести один тип к другому :

```
thread = new Threads(&Server::ThreadFunc, (void*) &i);
```

Или так, как указал [[@gkuznets](/users/5638/gkuznets)](/users/5638/gkuznets):

```
thread = new Threads(&Server::ThreadFunc, static_cast<void*> (&i));
```